# How to call C# Code from JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to call C# code  in the code behind from JavaScript ONLY when the validation in the JavaScript is true.  I am facing some issues with this can someone help.  Thanks
Here is my JavaScript

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function Validate_Checkbox() {
            var chks = $("#<%= cblCustomerList.ClientID %> input:checkbox");

            var hasChecked = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
                if (chks[i].checked) {
                    hasChecked = true;
                 //call C# code
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (hasChecked == false) {
                alert("Please select at least one checkbox..!");

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }     
    </script>
```

here is the C# code that i want to call

```
 protected void DV_Test_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {
       do something
    }
```

Here is the button that calls the JavaScript

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                            CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" OnClientClick="javascript:Validate_Checkbox();return true;"/>
```

Comment: You can add hidden button and bind some action you want to execute in `C#` code. And click this button after validation from `javascript`. It will cause postback ofc.

Comment: You can found an answer in http://michbex.com/wordpress/?p=66

Comment: i have looked all these suggestions but don't seem to find something that is easier so i can follow it.  my experience is javascript and c# is limited.  i will try to dig it some more info.

Answer (score 1):

Here the answer to your question [How to make an AJAX call without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

You might think however, in using JQuery which will simplify the way to write javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very good explanation on this topic

**1:** http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=109&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

**2:** http://forums.asp.net/t/1111231.aspx

I hope this help you ;-)

Or if you have the chance to use the library [**Telerik**] for ASP. You can call C # code easily with the controller [**RadAjaxManager**]

Answer (score 0):

we can use Ajax Call with data type

1) json , in this case you will create web method on the code behind and return string to JavaScript as return result

2) HTML , in this case you will call new HTML page and return HTML

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use server side event (Click) with combination of client side event. On the server side:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

and in the code behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something here
}
```

Additionally in your javascript code you should use `event.preventDefault()` if certain conditions are not met. Please check [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault) for details. The sample code on your client side could looks like (Not tested!):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#Button1').click(function(e){
    //some logic to check checkbox status and call e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: i want to make sure the Button1_Click fires only when the validation is true. I am not sure where to put that in my javascript.  my coding experience is very limited so please help if u can

Comment: i have tried this but it is not working for me can u please provide a working example?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Eval. Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Validate_Checkbox() {
        ...
        if (chks[i].checked) {
            hasChecked = true;
            eval("<%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(lbSubmit, String.Empty) %>");
        }
        ...
    }

<asp:Button ID="Button1" CausesValidation="True"  CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" OnClientClick="javascript:Validate_Checkbox();return true;" runat="server"/>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lbSubmit" style="display:none" OnClick="slbCheckVin_Click" runat="server"/>
```